# gmapping doesnt update the map on occasion

Tags: navigation, sicklms, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

i'm using lms100 and gmapping with laser scan matcher to build map.

in a narrow but long corridor, while i was going straight i notice that (thanks to LaserScan in rviz) map isnt updating. the built map should be so much longer but it didnt happen. in a normal room there wasnt any problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238514/gmapping-doesnt-update-the-map-on-occasion/) by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Long, straight hallways are hard to map due to a lack of features. The system has trouble localizing itself on the map as the scans all look the same until you see the end of the hallway. If you are able to modify the environment, try adding features and then compare the map without features to the one with features.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2016-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-06-30**:
that sounds reasonable, but in hector_slam i didnt have this probem, maybe it's because their algoritm are different right?

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-06-30**:
That's possible. I have used hector_mapping a lot more than gmapping as I don't have odometry

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-06-30**:
for mapping i prefer hector_slam too, i dont have odometry (or robot system :) but i want to see obstacles in costmap and i didnt manage to static map&amcl&costmap thing so till solving that, i'm doing laser scan matcher&gmapping&costmap, but in gmapping there is this problem too :/